# Using media queries: Why is the font so small on iPhone comared to desktop?

Tags: css, media-queries, font-size, iphone-5

My first time using media queries. Any changes to `div` size and other style changes work great. But the font is too small on mobile devices (*tested on iPhone 5s and a Samsung Galaxy 3*).

When I compare the site on a mobile device to the site in a narrow browser window, the font does not look like it's scaling proportional.

**Sample:**

The page in question can be viewed [Here](http://www.graceframe.com/):

**Code Sample:**

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 30em) and (orientation: portrait), 
only screen and (max-device-width: 30em) and (orientation: portrait) 
{
    body {
       -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; 
       font-size:100%;
    }
    #wrapper { 
       width:100%;
    }
    #horz-menu { 
       width:100%; 
       background-color:#828282; 
       background-image:none;
    }
    #menu-list { 
       float:none; 
       width:100%; 
       padding:18px 5px 5px 0px; 
       margin:0px; 
       font-size:1.3em; 
       text-align:center; 
    }
    #menu-list li { 
       display:inline; 
       border-right:1px solid #ECECEC; 
       padding-right:5px; 
       margin-left:5px
    }
    #topper { 
       display:none;
    }
    .footer-inner { 
       width:100%; 
       margin:0;
    }
    .customize {
       width:100%; 
       text-align:center; 
       border-right:none; 
       border-bottom: 1px solid #6B6B6B; 
       padding-top:15px; 
       float:none;
    }
    .customize img {
       width:100%;
    }
    #customOptions { 
        text-align:center; 
        width:100%;
    }
    #customOptions .acc-custom, 
    #customOptions .acc-custom-last, 
    #customOptions .acc-custom-last-off, 
    #customOptions .acc-custom-off{ 
        width:23%;
    }
    #accessories {
       width:100%; 
       float:none; 
       text-align:center; 
       padding-top:15px;
    }
    .acc-option { 
       float:left; 
       width:49%; 
       text-align:center; 
       font-weight:bold; 
       color:#545454; 
       margin-top:15px; 
       margin-bottom:15px;
    }
}
```

I'm still working on the site but I need to get the text to look the same on mobile as desktop. If I make it bigger in the mobile media query, the font looks huge on a small desktop window.

Why don't the fonts in mobile seem the same size as in a small window on the desktop?

Comment: You should take a look at this article. http://blog.cloudfour.com/the-ems-have-it-proportional-media-queries-ftw/ .... Sounds very similar to what you are experiencing.

Comment: I read that article at cloudfour. That's what lead me to use em's in the font size and query definition. I don't understand how to get the font size to look the same in a small desktop window and on an iPhone when font size is set to 1em for both.

Comment: just use a different font size  in your small screen media query.  Nobody will be viewing a desktop browser at a mobile width.

Comment: I think that's what I'll do Chris. I couldn't find any other information on this. Is this the general practice?